# How do I determine $\lim_{n\to \infty}P(|\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}X_i - n^2|\leq n^{\alpha})$ where $(x_i)$ is a sequence of random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

Let $x_1, x_2, \dotsb$ be a sequence of independent random variables distributed uniformly on the interval $[0, 2]$. Find all possible values of the following limit, where $\alpha$ is a positive number:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}P\left(\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}X_i - n^2\right|\leq n^{\alpha}\right).$$

Comment: You can get properly sized absolute value bars (and other paired delimiters) that adjust to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Answer (score 1):

The $X_i$ have mean $\mu=1$ and variance $\sigma^2=\frac13$. By the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem), the distribution of

$$
S_n=\frac n\sigma\frac1{n^2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}(X_i-\mu)\right)
$$

converges to the standard normal distribution for $n\to\infty$. As

$$
\left|\,\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}X_i-n^2\,\right|\le n^\alpha
$$

is equivalent to

$$
|S_n|\le\frac{n^{\alpha-1}}\sigma\;,
$$

the limit is $0$ if $\alpha\lt1$, $1$ if $\alpha\gt1$, and

$$
\operatorname{erf}\left({\sqrt\frac32}\right)\approx0.917
$$

if $\alpha=1$.

Comment: If honestly, not quite clear why $\left|\,\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}X_i-n^2\,\right|\le n^\alpha$ is equivalent to $|S_n|\le\frac{n^{\alpha-1}}\sigma$

Comment: @KaterynaKrén: Substitute $S_n$ into your second inequality from the definition (in the first displayed equation in the answer), cancel the factors $\frac1{\sigma n}$ on both sides, and note that $\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}1=n^2$.